# Reading protobuf messages via winpcap API

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, winpcap

I'm using winpcap to capture network traffic, and I know for a fact that this traffic mainly consists of serialized Protocol Buffer exchanges. How can I detect those messages in the traffic if I know all the types of message that a system is likely to transmit?

Answer (score 0):

This will be a bit difficult, because protocol buffers are not self-describing and when you read through a raw stream of bytes there is no easy way to determine when one message ends and another begins. However, with a bit of effort you may be able to recover some of the data if you have a good understanding of the wire format.

The protocol buffer [wire format](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding) essentially consists of a series of key-value pairs. Each key represents a field number and wire type (together called a tag), and the value is the actual data associated with that field number. If you know the messages you're looking for, I would start by searching for the tags you expect to see based on the types and fields numbers in your message definitions. You will have to read the documentation at the link above to figure out how to calculate the tag and format it as a varint, and then search for those raw varint bytes. Once you have found what appears to be a tag, you will have to try to parse the message from there, making an educated guess about where the message ends.